# Laravel Http Client User-Agent header as -A

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-http-client

How can I pass `User-Agent` header with a especial curl parameter `-A`, not `-H`?

[image: official curl docs]

This code adds `User-Agent` with `-H` parameter, not `-A`:

```php
Http::withHeaders(['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 13; Mobile; rv:109.0) Gecko/111.0 Firefox/111.0'])
```

This code has no effect:

```php
Http::beforeSending(function(Illuminate\Http\Client\Request $request) {
    $request->toPsrRequest()
        ->withHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 13; Mobile; rv:109.0) Gecko/111.0 Firefox/111.0');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Http::withOptions([
    'CURLOPT_USERAGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 13; Mobile; rv:109.0) Gecko/111.0 Firefox/111.0',
]);
```

Comment: Still not working :(